# Change the color of a specific icon in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, icons, jquery-mobile-listview

I wrote the following code, but I want my home icon to be in blue, for example. How can I change it background color?

```
  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon">
        <li><a href="#page_1" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-right" data-role="link" style="text-align: center; font: bold arial 95px;">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-shop ui-btn-icon-right" data-role="link" style="text-align: center;">Products</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: the code:       <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon">
            <li><a href="#page_1" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-right" data-role="link" style="text-align: center; font: bold arial 95px;">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-shop ui-btn-icon-right" data-role="link" style="text-align: center;">Products</a></li>

        </ul>

Comment: http://www.bar54.de/2014/02/jquery-mobile-change-color-of-svg-icons/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `:after` CSS selector to override button's icon. You also have to be specific when overriding *global classes* in order not to apply changes made on all buttons.

```
ul.ui-nodisc-icon li:first-child .ui-btn:after {
  background-color: #4da6ff;
}
```

The above will be be applied only on `first-child` of the listview. You can replace `li:first-child` & `.ui-btn` with an `id` or `class` added to *anchor*, e.g.:

```
<ul data-role="listview">
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="home">Home</a>
  </li>
</ul>

ul.ui-nodisc-icon #home:after {
  background-color: #4da6ff;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/5YwjN/)**

Comment: Thanks dude, after trying like crazy to do this with jquery examples this answer got it working right away.